# Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? when calling public variable from web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a public contract variable: `uint public bidEnd`, and I'm getting its value using web3js like so:

```
new web3.eth.Contract(json, address).methods.bidEnd().call(function(err, res){
    console.log("err is ", err);
    console.log(res);
};
```

And it's printing the following in the console:

```
err is  Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at require.decodeParametersWith (index.js:299)
    at require.decodeParameters (index.js:286)
    at Contract.global._decodeMethodReturn (index.js:471)
    at Method.outputFormatter (index.js:761)
    at Method.formatOutput (index.js:148)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js:524)
    at cb (util.js:703)
    at Item.run (browser.js:154)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:124)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: You should share the code of `bidEnd`

Comment: bidEnd is a public variable. Solidity compiler creates getters automatically for public variables

Comment: From the error message the function returns something that isn't expected by the js code, so likely the call failed. What blockchain are you using? public testnet, ganache, private network. Do any other function work?

Comment: No functions were working until I re-deployed the contracts

Comment: @lampbottle There isn't enough code to test. The function `outputFormatter` appears in the stack trace so it looks like something went wrong while reading the result, so either the contract reverted and returned something that doesn't match the expected output or the abi is wrong/old and web3 fails when decoding the returned output.